# With Symfony2 and Swiftmailer, how do I listen for exceptions thrown when spooled emails are actually sent?

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer and Symfony to send email. My config is set to spool the email, and I'm using a third-party SMTP server (MailJet). It all works fine. ***But if I give Swiftmailer a wrong password for the SMTP server, it just fails silently.***

When I turn off spooling so that it's sent immediately, I see that Swiftmailer is throwing a TransportException. However, when it's being spooled, this Exception is thrown during Symfony's `kernel.terminate` event so it just gets ignored. There's nothing in the logs of either Symfony or nginx so I don't actually know whether the exception is thrown.

So how can I detect a failure to connect to the SMTP server if it's thrown during the `kernel.terminate` event so that I can log it in Monolog?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Swiftmailer plugins](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#). There are a bunch that come [included with swift](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tree/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Plugins).

Maybe the [logger](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Plugins/LoggerPlugin.php) plugin or the [reporter](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Plugins/ReporterPlugin.php) plugin are enough for you.

If not you can write your own plugin/event listener. You can take a look at how the logger plugin works, it listens to exceptions by implementing the [transport exception listener](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Events/TransportExceptionListener.php).

Something like this:

```
class CustomPlugin implements Swift_Events_TransportExceptionListener
{
    public function exceptionThrown(Swift_Events_TransportExceptionEvent $evt)
    {
        $e = $evt->getException();
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

Then you can register your plugin like this:

```
$mailer->registerPlugin(new CustomPlugin());
```